# Helm charts: Are you allowed children directories within the Templates directory?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

This seems like a really simple question but I couldn't find a straight answer to it.

My question is, are you allowed children directories within the `templates` directory of a Helm chart? i.e, something like this:

```
mychart/
|-- Chart.yaml
|-- charts
|-- templates/
|   |-- NOTES.txt
|   |-- _helpers.tpl
|   |-- deployment.yaml
|   |-- ingress.yaml
|   |-- service.yaml
|   |-- child-dir1/
|   |   |-- some-file-1.yaml
|   |   `-- some-file-2.yaml
|   `-- child-dir2/
|       |-- some-file-3.yaml
|       `-- some-file-4.yaml
`-- values.yaml
```

I already understand the most basic file structure which can be found with a simple google search:

```
mychart
|-- Chart.yaml
|-- charts
|-- templates
|   |-- NOTES.txt
|   |-- _helpers.tpl
|   |-- deployment.yaml
|   |-- ingress.yaml
|   `-- service.yaml
`-- values.yaml
```

I'm just wanting a straight answer about whether or not you can use subdirectories within the `templates` directory. My initial thought would be no, but I'd like confirmation and maybe an explanation on why that is not possible with the current design of Helm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got around to working on some Helm charts again and decided to experiment with this and it seems that you can create as many child directories as you want. This was for a library chart however, so each `yaml` or `tpl` file has a definition at the top of the file which is called whenever it is used.

Here's my directory structure showing that this can be done:
[image: Helm repo directory structure]

I'm still not 100% sure if this works with application charts, however, I suspect they would still work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The [Helm documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#templates-and-values) only states that "every file in that [`templates`] directory" will be processed.  There's no specific mention of subdirectories and that language hints subdirectories aren't considered.

In the [source code](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v3.13.1/pkg/chart/loader/load.go#L141-L142), though, the Helm chart loader works by reading a directory into memory and iterating through the files.  The more specific check is

```golang
case strings.HasPrefix(f.Name, "templates/"):
    c.Templates = append(c.Templates, &chart.File{Name: f.Name, Data: f.Data})
```

which is to say, any file anywhere in the chart's `templates/` tree (whose relative path begins with a `templates/` prefix, regardless of whether there are more slashes) is considered a valid template.

One easy way to see this is by constructing a trivial chart:

```bash
mkdir chart; cd chart
echo 'name: foo' > Chart.yaml
echo 'version: "0.0.0"' >> Chart.yaml
mkdir templates; mkdir templates/x
echo 'apiVersion: v1' > templates/x/y.yaml
helm template .
```

and you will see that Helm does in fact read and render the file in the `templates/x` subdirectory.

Comment: (I suspect, if your chart is complex enough that you're looking at this, then breaking it into subcharts is more idiomatic; create a `charts/x/templates` directory and put your nested template files there.)

Comment: In this specific instance, I'm using Helm to easily apply a bunch of RBAC Roles and RoleBindings. At the moment I'm keeping the templates with very minimal configuration (I only have 2 values). I was wanting to see if this was possible so I can organise the Role/RoleBinding pairs in a nicer way. 

Thanks for your answer! I'll give it a try soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you after is "Umbrella chart", have a look [here](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#complex-charts-with-many-dependencies)

Basically you need to use "charts" folder instead of "templates" and in subfolder you can have its onw chart definition with "templates" folder

Comment: Thank you, but no, this is exactly not what I'm looking for. This is using other Helm charts as dependencies, I just want to organise the templates in child directories to make the `templates` directory more organised and neater